# Can the boundedness of the domain omitted?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Let $\Omega$ be an open connected domain. Suppose $u\in C^2(\Omega)$ satisfies
$\Delta u + c(x)u\geq0$, where $c\in C(\Omega)$ and $c(x)\leq0$.

My question asks that if $u$ attains its maximum in $\Omega$, i.e., if there exists $x_0\in\Omega$ such that $u(x_0 )=M$ where $M=\sup_{x\in\Omega}u(x)$, then $u\equiv M$.

I can show this under the assumption that $\Omega$ is bounded, but I'm not sure if this is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

Let $B$ be a ball centered at $x_0$, and write $A:=B\cap \Omega$. By the bounded case, you know that $u$ is constant on $A$. As this is true for an arbitrary $B$, we deduce that $u$ is constant on $\Omega$.

Note that the above argument has nothing to do with PDE's. It is in fact the following observation.

**Fact:** Let $\Omega$ be a metric space and let $u:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$. If $u$ is constant on bounded sets in $\Omega$, then $u$ is constant on all $\Omega$.

Comment: Small nitpick: $A$ might not be connected.

Comment: @gerw  $\Omega$ is connected.

Comment: It is true that $A$ may be disconnected, but as $\Omega$ is connected, we can avoid disconnectivity by taking $B$ to be big enough.

Comment: Really? What about a wiggling spiral, e.g., (in polar coordinates) $\{(r, \varphi) : r \in \varphi + \sin(\varphi) + (-1,1)/10 \}$?

Comment: @grew The domain $\Omega$ is open and connected, and hence path connected. So, for any two points in $\Omega$, there is a path connecting these two points. This path is contained in a ball $B$. It is true that $\Omega\cap B$ may be still disconnected, but still, applying the bounded case to one connected component in $\Omega\cap B$ proves that $u$ admits the same value in the chosen two points. This can be done, of course, for any two points.